# Sending JSON Data to Solr using cUrl

Tags: json, apache, curl, cmd, solr

How do I can send JSON object to solr collection usinc cUrl

I'm using Windows 10.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" "http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update/json/docs" --data-binary "{'id': '1','title':'Doc 1'}"
```

When I'm using this format I'm getting some kind of warning message:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/sorl_sample/update/json/docs' --data-binary '{"id": "1","title":"Doc 1"}'
curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
```

I resolved it using **" "** insted of **' '**

When I send the request using the first url I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":112}}
```

But when I try to get some result by searching I can't see any object in *docs[]*

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/select?q=*:*"
```

Result:

```
{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0,
        "params":{
          "q":"*:*"}},
      "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
      }}
```

When I'm using Solr UI I can add JSON objects without any problems, also to see the result in terminal

Comment: You have to commit the update. Add commit=true to the request.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" "http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update?commit=true" --data-
binary "{'id':'1'}"`

I'm getting this error:

`<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/solr_sample/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to commit the update. Add commit true or commitWithin 1000 to the request, e. g.

curl -X POST -d '{"add":{"doc":{"id":"delete.me","title":"change.me"},"commitWithin":1000}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update

Does also work:

curl -X POST -d '{"add":{ "doc":{"id":"delete.me","title":"change.me"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update?commit=true

Comment: Tester both commands and unfortunatelly doesn't work. I'm getting the error messages

`curl -X POST -d '{"add":{ "doc":{"id":"2","title":"Random title"}}}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update?commit=true`

`curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 29
Error 404 Not Found
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/solr_sample/update. Reason:
Not Found`

Comment: `curl -X POST -d '{"add":{"doc":{"id":"2","title":"Title 2"},"commitWithin":1000}}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8983/solr/solr_sample/update/` 

`<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/solr_sample/update/. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes, e. g. "{\"add\":{...}}" or "{'add':{...}}". Maybe curl does behave different on Windows than on UNIX and OS X, the platforms I am working on.

Comment: I just tested on Ubuntu 16 and works good. Thank you man, you are amazing!